# angularJs - handling an error and setting property of the child scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, exception

Our application app.js file has several http error interceptors. They have the following line in them:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("sm:serverError", errors);
```

The serverError directive is added to the layout.html file which is used in all our index pages (e.g. main lists). From the index page we open the edit form and in the edit form we have buttons. These buttons have

```
ng-disabled="disableAction"
```

in the controller's code that handles our save (and other actions) we set this property to true before calling the actual save (which is an asynchronous api call) and then set it back to false in the .then for that call.

The problem is when we have an error which is being intercepted by these interceptors and that directive method is called, I'd like to somehow reset the disableAction back to false. However, the scopes are different, so I cannot figure out how to reset this flag for our forms.

Perhaps you have ideas on what can we do and if there is a generic solution to this problem. Hopefully I explained the problem well.

Comment: Why not broadcast a `sm:serverErrorCleared` event after editing, listen to it from the same context that listens to the initial event, and trigger a different function in the controller that resets the property?

Comment: That would require changing code in all our controllers. I was hoping for a simpler solution, this one did occur to me too.

Comment: I'm going to try that approach in one particular controller's code, though. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: This suggestion worked great in one place I tried it. I'm going to add it to all our controllers then, thanks again.